# Cannot reconnect to wifi

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, iwlwifi

I am running Xubuntu 20.04 and have a problem with wifi reconnects: Sometimes my HP notebook loses connection to the wifi router (3 meters distance, without obstacles) and then cannot reconnect. This is the corresponding excerpt from syslog:

```
Jun 24 21:50:26 hostname wpa_supplicant[1026]: wlp58s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 34:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (SSID='homewifi_5G-2' freq=5500 MHz)
Jun 24 21:50:26 hostname kernel: [ 6469.357476] wlp58s0: send auth to 34:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (try 1/3)
Jun 24 21:50:26 hostname NetworkManager[7166]: <info>  [1593028226.5142] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jun 24 21:50:26 hostname NetworkManager[7166]: <info>  [1593028226.5142] device (p2p-dev-wlp58s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jun 24 21:50:27 hostname kernel: [ 6469.972019] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
Jun 24 21:50:27 hostname kernel: [ 6469.972083] wlp58s0: Connection to AP 34:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx lost
Jun 24 21:50:27 hostname kernel: [ 6470.021469] wlp58s0: send auth to 34:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (try 2/3)
Jun 24 21:50:27 hostname kernel: [ 6470.635771] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
Jun 24 21:50:27 hostname kernel: [ 6470.635821] wlp58s0: Connection to AP 34:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx lost
Jun 24 21:50:28 hostname kernel: [ 6471.013103] wlp58s0: send auth to 34:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (try 3/3)
Jun 24 21:50:28 hostname kernel: [ 6471.627473] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
Jun 24 21:50:28 hostname kernel: [ 6471.627570] wlp58s0: Connection to AP 34:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx lost
Jun 24 21:50:29 hostname kernel: [ 6472.004632] wlp58s0: authentication with 34:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx timed out
Jun 24 21:50:29 hostname wpa_supplicant[1026]: wlp58s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="homewifi_5G-2" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=CONN_FAILED
Jun 24 21:50:29 hostname NetworkManager[7166]: <info>  [1593028229.1939] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Jun 24 21:50:29 hostname NetworkManager[7166]: <info>  [1593028229.1940] device (p2p-dev-wlp58s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Jun 24 21:50:30 hostname systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
Jun 24 21:50:39 hostname NetworkManager[7166]: <info>  [1593028239.1966] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jun 24 21:50:39 hostname NetworkManager[7166]: <info>  [1593028239.1967] device (p2p-dev-wlp58s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jun 24 21:50:40 hostname wpa_supplicant[1026]: wlp58s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=0 ssid="homewifi_5G-2"
Jun 24 21:50:40 hostname wpa_supplicant[1026]: wlp58s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 34:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (SSID='homewifi_5G-2' freq=5500 MHz)
Jun 24 21:50:40 hostname kernel: [ 6482.882772] wlp58s0: authenticate with 34:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Jun 24 21:50:40 hostname kernel: [ 6482.888639] wlp58s0: send auth to 34:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (try 1/3)
Jun 24 21:50:40 hostname NetworkManager[7166]: <info>  [1593028240.0444] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jun 24 21:50:40 hostname NetworkManager[7166]: <info>  [1593028240.0445] device (p2p-dev-wlp58s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jun 24 21:50:40 hostname kernel: [ 6483.502938] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
Jun 24 21:50:40 hostname kernel: [ 6483.503033] wlp58s0: Connection to AP 34:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx lost
Jun 24 21:50:41 hostname kernel: [ 6484.037725] wlp58s0: send auth to 34:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (try 2/3)
Jun 24 21:50:41 hostname kernel: [ 6484.652032] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
Jun 24 21:50:41 hostname kernel: [ 6484.652110] wlp58s0: Connection to AP 34:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx lost
Jun 24 21:50:42 hostname kernel: [ 6484.999095] wlp58s0: send auth to 34:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (try 3/3)
Jun 24 21:50:42 hostname kernel: [ 6485.613299] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
Jun 24 21:50:42 hostname kernel: [ 6485.613377] wlp58s0: Connection to AP 34:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx lost
Jun 24 21:50:43 hostname kernel: [ 6485.989445] wlp58s0: authentication with 34:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx timed out
Jun 24 21:50:43 hostname wpa_supplicant[1026]: wlp58s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="homewifi_5G-2" auth_failures=2 duration=20 reason=CONN_FAILED
Jun 24 21:50:43 hostname NetworkManager[7166]: <info>  [1593028243.1721] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Jun 24 21:50:43 hostname NetworkManager[7166]: <info>  [1593028243.1722] device (p2p-dev-wlp58s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Jun 24 21:50:50 hostname systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Succeeded.
Jun 24 21:50:51 hostname NetworkManager[7166]: <warn>  [1593028251.0630] device (wlp58s0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation
Jun 24 21:50:51 hostname NetworkManager[7166]: <info>  [1593028251.0631] device (wlp58s0): state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 24 21:50:51 hostname NetworkManager[7166]: <info>  [1593028251.0648] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Jun 24 21:50:51 hostname NetworkManager[7166]: <warn>  [1593028251.0680] device (wlp58s0): Activation: failed for connection 'homewifi_5G-2'
Jun 24 21:50:51 hostname NetworkManager[7166]: <info>  [1593028251.0692] device (wlp58s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
```

My mobile phone connects without problems, but my Linux notebook doesn't. After a reboot, everything is fine again, but a simple `sudo service network-manager restart` doesn't do the trick. Any clues?

Some wifi details:

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3a:00.0
       logical name: wlp58s0
       version: 1a
       serial: 5c:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-37-generic firmware=48.4fa0041f.0 ip=192.168.1.96 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:19 memory:c8100000-c8103fff
```

And my kernel information:

```
$ uname -a
Linux hostname 5.4.0-37-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 3 18:57:02 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

*EDIT*
As requested:

```
$ iwlist wlp58s0 freq
wlp58s0   32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz
          Current Frequency:5.26 GHz (Channel 52)
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `iwlist wlp58s0 freq`, and tell me what channel your router is set to on the homewifi_5G-2 network. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Thanks for your response @heynnema ! Checked the ASUS dashboard and it shows homewifi_5G-2: Channel 100/80 MHz

Comment: That's strange, as the `iwlist` shows that you're connected to channel 52. Do you have more than one wireless network, either 2.4 or 5GHz? Does your ASUS router go to channel 140... or any of the other higher channel numbers showing in the `iwlist` command (high channels are better)?

Comment: Yes @heynnema ! I have 5 networks in total: One 2.4GHz on Channel 11 and one 2.4GHz guest network. Additionally, I have two 5GHz networks, one on 52/80 MHz and one on 100/80 MHz. Finally, one 5GHz guest network. Is there any more information I can provide? :)

Comment: You didn't say what channels the guest networks were set to. What happens when you connect to the "other" 5GHz network on channel 100? What brand router, just curious.

Comment: Does the router allow you to custom adjust beacon time, and channel width? What connection type... WPA2/AES? How old is the HP notebook? Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the exact model # of your HP.

Comment: Sorry for the late response @heynnema ! The guest networks use the same channel as the main ones (https://www.snbforums.com/threads/does-guest-networks-run-on-different-channel-than-the-main-router.48368/#post-424061) - I also didn't know that :) The router is the Asus AC5300. All of the connections (normal and guest networks) are WPA2 with AES. `$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version 
R70 Ver. 01.04.05`. My notebook is three months old and the exact model is the HP 830 G6. I can adjust the beacon interval (currently set to 100). And yes, I can adjust the channel bandwidth for each SSID :)

Comment: Thanks for all your effort @heynnema ! I will check this on the weekend and will report back- either with more questions or a cllick on the accept checkmark :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**BIOS**

HP 830 G6

You have BIOS version R70 01.04.05.

There's a newer BIOS available that appears to address a network problem, vesrion R70 01.05.03 Rev.A, dated 05/11/2020, and can be downloaded [here](https://support.hp.com/gb-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-elitebook-830-g6-notebook-pc/26609813).

Note: Verify that I have the correct web page for your model #.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

Comment: So far it works. I will let you know, if I experience the same behavior after some time. Thanks again :)

Comment: @JJAbrams Great news! Thanks for the update.